# Why does Java Web Start request that the main JAR and linked components of my application be installed since 1.7.0_21?

Tags: java, java-web-start

Let's say you have a multi-component Java Web Start application, which is composed of a JNLP referencing your main application's JAR and multiple other JNLPs as `component-desc`.

For some reason, since the 1.7.0_21 version (Java SE 7 Update 21), Web Start seems to prompt the user with an installation request for **all** of these (the main JAR - or main JNLP - and all the JNLPs listed as `component-desc` entries), whereas previous versions of Web Start seemed to only prompt the user to install the main component (the top-level JNLP containing the "main" JAR).

As you can imagine, this is a serious problem as a heavily modularized application or one relying on 3rd party components and linking to their own JNLPs will end up with a pretty unfriendly startup process for the uses, who may be requested to click through a lot of dialogs before being able to start their applications.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*I'm posting my own answer directly, as after weeks of wondering why this was happening we finally figured out the one thing that triggered this behavior. Please feel free to post your own answers to add to the discussion.*</sup>

### The Root Cause

Since Java SE 7 Update 21, the Web Start launcher will treat differently remote servers using uppercase and lowercase letters in their hostnames when launching the JNLP.

Hence, launching a JNLP using the following alternate spellings will trigger different behaviors:

- **[EVIL]** using upppercase will trigger the behavior mentioned in the question (e.g. `http://MYDOMAIN.COM/webapp/webstart.jnlp`)
- **[GOOD]** using lowercase will function as expected and intended (e.g. `http://maydomain.com/webapp/webstart.jnlp`)

*Note:* The reasoning behind this isn't explained the release notes for 1.7.0_21.

### The Solution

Simply don't use uppercase characters when linking resources that will be loaded over the JNLP protocol via Web Start.

If your system uses uppercase hostnames (for any reason, which probably isn't a valid one - see the next section below), then do convert them to lowercase before invoking the Web Start launcher or constructing the URL that it will use for launching.

### Hostname Case-Insensitivity

It is to be noted that the [RFC952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc952.txt) assumes hostnames thusly <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>:

**A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
   to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
   sign (-), and period (.).**  Note that periods are only allowed when
   they serve to delimit components of "domain style names". (See
   RFC-921, "Domain Name System Implementation Schedule", for
   background).  No blank or space characters are permitted as part of a
   name. **No distinction is made between upper and lower case.**  The first
   character must be an alpha character.  The last character must not be
   a minus sign or period.  A host which serves as a GATEWAY should have
   "-GATEWAY" or "-GW" as part of its name.  Hosts which do not serve as
   Internet gateways should not use "-GATEWAY" and "-GW" as part of
   their names. A host which is a TAC should have "-TAC" as the last
   part of its host name, if it is a DoD host.  Single character names
   or nicknames are not allowed.

If your system requires uppercase characters for some reason, it's doing something wrong; as is Web Start, apparently, as of 1.7.0_21, unfortunately.

---

Note that I haven't seen and am not aware at this time of a bug report in Oracle's database, and that the signal for this problem seems rather low online, so other conditions may trigger this behavior. I haven't worked out a simplistic test-case yet.